# Twitter OAuth via a popup

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, oauth

I was wondering how to do twitter OAuth via a popup, i.e. load up the Oauth page in a popup and make the callback close the child window and reload the parent window.

Edit: OK iframes are bad, but how would you accomplish the above, I notice posterous.com does this - I'm looking to achieve the same flow as FB connect.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Doing the same thing for Yahoo today...

1. Open a popup
2. Send user to twitter for authentication
3. Twitter sends user back to mysite.com/authcompleted.php, with authentication parameters in the query string. Still in the popup here.
4. The popup (mysite.com/authcompleted.html) reads the query string and sends the data to the opener window via javascript

   window.opener.setTwitterAuthData(yourData)
5. Inside setTwitterAuthData, which is in your main window, set appropriate form fields and submit the data to your server.

Comment: how can you still be in the popup, point 3., when the callback is mysite.com/authcompleted.php?

Comment: @mark You point the popup to yahoo to begin with, then yahoo redirects, still inside the popup, to authcompleted.php

Comment: How do you detect when the redirect had happened and there is a response?

Comment: Yes, i use the same flow, but what about mobile devices?? 
Its it correct flow for it?

Comment: now working if you write incorrect password and redirect happen. window.opener not defined

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't do this. Loading it in an IFrame hides the URL from the user, making it difficult for them to confirm that they're entering their password on twitter.com and not a third-party (i.e. phishing) site.

Comment: I agree in principle, but doesn't the auth page only have allow || deny this application buttons - it doesn't ask you for your password. So I can't see why it should be a problem from a security perspective, while helping the UX flow.

Comment: If you're not logged in it asks you for your password.

Comment: There is iframe busting JS on the non-logged in page where it asks you for your password (line 37)

Comment: Twitter's OAuth page now uses the `X-Frame-Options` header to prevent loading it in an iframe :)

Answer (score 6):

This maybe helpful!

http://zuzara.com/blog/2010/05/15/jquery-plugin-for-twitter-oauth-via-popup-window-facebook-style/

Comment: If you're developing on Windows you can find the pecl oauth dll at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/