# Sign In With Twitter

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

Looking at this site http://www.thefancy.com/ and clicking the Sign up button followed by the Twitter option it brings up a window for Twitter Login.

I assume this is the JS approach to Twitter login in a similar fashion to Facebooks.

On my site I have already implemented Connect With Facebook (using JS) and to keep my site consistent I would like to know how to do this using Twitter's Sign On service.

Does anyone have any useful advice or links to help me with this - I can only find guides that take the user to Twitter's website during login and then back again to mine which is not what I want.

Many thanks

EDIT:
I did notice this on Twitter's site:
"Reminder: It is strongly discouraged to use OAuth 1.0A with client-side Javascript."

Why do Twitter recommend against using JS with OAuth while Facebook and Google are happy to go with it?

Answer (score 1):

tHave you looked into [Twitter OAuth](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth)? In order for Twitter to grand your site details, it has to redirect your users momentarily to twitter for them to verify this access. This link explains it a bit better: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth

Comment: Hi - yes I've seen that but it seems focused on sending users to their site (Twitter) and not done in a popup window. I need a JS approach to Twitter login like that on thefancy.com but I'm struggling to find any resources on the web that do it like this - it's easy on Facebook and on Google's new sign in service but not on Twitter.

Comment: I think this answer is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878529/twitter-oauth-via-a-popup

Answer (score 0):

Temboo simplifies the process of developing Twitter sign up (via OAuth). See here for details: https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter/OAuth/

Temboo doesn't have a JS library though, so you will have to use the REST API.

Full disclosure: I work at Temboo.