# How do I authenticate Twitter user with oauth without reloading page (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter's api through [twitter-lite][1] to log in and post as a user.

Right now I redirect the user to twitter, which sends back the necessary oauth token for me to post as them.

But I want to be able to do this from a form with other data on it, without leaving that form page and losing the data. Is this possible? Or does the user have to be logged in first?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878529/twitter-oauth-via-a-popup

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the solution